# Print value from the next line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have file looks like that

```
User Charts
User ID:
40944827
User Name:
Joe, Neo
Gender:
M
DOB:
3/20/2000 12:00:00 AM - Age: 20 yr. 10 mo. old
```

I want to use `awk` or `sed` to get results in format of

```
LastName, First Name,Gender,DOB

Joe,Neo,M,3/20/2000
```

Comment: This might help with GNU sed as first step: `sed '/:/{N;s/\n//}' file`

Comment: Where do "LastName" and "First Name" come from? They're not in your input file. Will "User Name" _always_ be `FirstName, LastName`? Does the file only have those lines you show or can you have the data for multiple users in the same file?

Comment: hi@terdon

LastName" and "First Name is just an example

for now I can get the results using NR in awk

``` awk 'NR>=5 && NR<=5 { print }' 
```

Comment: If your real data has more than 1 record then show more than 1 record in your sample input/output. Things like how the records are separated matter. wrt the script in [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567806/print-value-from-the-next-line#comment1055835_567806) `awk 'NR>=5 && NR<=5 { print }'` - **think** about for which value of `NR` it'd be true that `NR>=5 && NR<=5`. Big hint: `NR==5`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with awk since that is what you asked for.  The solution is valid for any number of records in your data file, called `datafile`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "FirstName,LastName,Gender,DOB"}
       /User Name:|Gender:/ {dob=0;rtp=NR+1} 
       NR==rtp && dob==0 {printf $1 $2 ","} 
       /DOB:/ {dob=1;rtp=NR+1} 
       NR==rtp && dob==1 {print $1}' datafile
[output]
FirstName,LastName,Gender,DOB
Joe,Neo,M,3/20/2000
```

**Line 1**: print output's header:"FirstName,LastName,Gender,DOB"

**Line 2**: if record contains either "User name:" or "Gender:" set internal variables dob and rtp to 0 and NR+1 respectively.

**Line 3**: if record number is rtp and dob is 0, print two first field if they are non-empty

**Line 4**: if record contains "DOB:" set internal variables dob and rtp to 1 and NR+1 respectively.

**Line 5**: if record number is rtp and dob is 1, print first field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real input file contains more than 1 record, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
User Charts
User ID:
40944827
User Name:
Joe, Neo
Gender:
M
DOB:
3/20/2000 12:00:00 AM - Age: 20 yr. 10 mo. old
User ID:
1234
User Name:
Bob, Slob
Gender:
X
DOB:
5/28/2000 12:00:00 AM - Age: 20 yr. 10 mo. old
```

Here's how you can convert that to a CSV without coupling the code to the values of the input lines:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==1   { next }
!(NR%2) { sub(/:.*/,""); hdrs[++numFlds]=$0 }
NR%2    { vals[numFlds]=$0 }
!((NR-1)%8) {
    if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
            printf "\"%s\"%s", hdrs[fldNr], (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        printf "\"%s\"%s", vals[fldNr], (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    numFlds = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"User ID","User Name","Gender","DOB"
"40944827","Joe, Neo","M","3/20/2000 12:00:00 AM - Age: 20 yr. 10 mo. old"
"1234","Bob, Slob","X","5/28/2000 12:00:00 AM - Age: 20 yr. 10 mo. old"
```

It's not exactly the output you were looking for but it might actually be more useful for you and hopefully you can see that it's just a tweak in the `for` loops to make any decisions based on data values and change the output for the selected field(s) as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html). Like awk, it has a built-in concept of records and fields - but unlike awk, it natively handles key-value pairs as well.

Ex.

```
mlr --idkvp --irs '\0' --ifs '\n' --ips ':\n' --ocsvlite put -S '
  u = splitnvx(${User Name},", "); $FirstName = u[1]; $LastName = u[2]; 
  d = splitnvx($DOB," "); $DOB = d[1]
' then cut -o -f 'FirstName,LastName,Gender,DOB' file
FirstName,LastName,Gender,DOB
Joe,Neo,M,3/20/2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with sed:

```
sed -e 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/.*Name:\n\([^[:space:]]*, [^[:space:]]*\)\nGender:\n\(.\)\nDOB:\n\([^[:space:]]*\).*/LastName, First Name,Gender,DOB\n\n\1,\2,\3/'
```

whereby I think the output should look more like this:  ;-)

```
sed -e 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/.*Name:\n\([^[:space:]]*, [^[:space:]]*\)\nGender:\n\(.\)\nDOB:\n\([^[:space:]]*\).*/LastName, FirstName, Gender, DOB\n\n\1, \2, \3/'
```